# Printing result into two columns error for java

Tags: java, output

Its just as the title stated I want to print something into two columns but I seem to be running to an error.

```
int noOfHorseInList = 7;
        String horseName[] = {"Blitz", "Sparky", "Sandy", "Rolo", "Beano", 

"Flash", "", "", ""};
        int horseAge[] = {2, 4, 1, 4, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0};
        int timeTakenInSeconds[] = {600, -1, 500, 430, 412, -1, 0, 0, 0};

    int option = 0;

    System.out.println("Please choose from the following selection");
    System.out.println("1. Show horses that finished\n2. Show horse details\n3. Adding a Late Entrant");
    option = kb.nextInt();
    kb.hasNextLine();

    switch(option)
    {
    case 1:
        //Finishers
        String showHorseThatFinished = "";
        showHorseThatFinished = finishers(noOfHorseInList, horseName, timeTakenInSeconds);

        String timeOfHorse = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < noOfHorseInList; i++)
        {
            if(timeTakenInSeconds[i] > -1)
            {
                timeOfHorse = timeOfHorse + "\n" + timeTakenInSeconds[i];
            }
        }


        System.out.println("Horses Name\tFinishing Time");
        System.out.println(showHorseThatFinished + "\t" + timeOfHorse);



        break;

    case 2:
        //Horse details





        break;

    case 3:
        //Adding Late Entrant



        break;

    }

}

public static String finishers(int noOfHorseInList,String horseName[],int timeTakenInSeconds[])
{
    String showHorseThatFinished = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < noOfHorseInList; i++)
    {
        if(timeTakenInSeconds[i] > -1)
        {
            showHorseThatFinished = showHorseThatFinished + "\n" + horseName[i];
        }
    }


    return showHorseThatFinished;
}
```

This is my output, I want the values into two columns next to each other

[image]

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: not an error I need to add but I want the output shown on the image to appear on a different column rather than on the one column. The problem I cant seem to figure out how to do this.

Comment: You are calling finishers() which prints all of the horses. Then you run through a for loop which prints all of times. If you want them in the same line you need to print them all in the same for loop at the same time. Basically get rid of your finishers function

Comment: yup that was the problem, thanks dude :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually calculating too much...

take a look at this method:
**finishers(int noOfHorseInList, String horseName[], int timeTakenInSeconds[])**

modify it like this:

```
public static String finishers(int noOfHorseInList, String horseName[], int timeTakenInSeconds[]) {
        String showHorseThatFinished = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < noOfHorseInList; i++) {
            if (timeTakenInSeconds[i] > -1) {
                showHorseThatFinished = showHorseThatFinished + "\n" + horseName[i] + "\t\t\t" + timeTakenInSeconds[i];
            }
        }
        return showHorseThatFinished;

    }
```

and your table will be done with no need of the

```
for(int i = 0; i < noOfHorseInList; i++)
        {
```

in the **case 1:**

Answer (score 0):

Append horse names and times in the same function.

Use StringBuffer for appending. It's more efficient.

```
public static String finishers(int noOfHorseInList,String   horseName[],int timeTakenInSeconds[]) {
StringBuffer showHorseThatFinished = new StringBuffer();

for(int i = 0; i < noOfHorseInList; i++) {
        // You need all horses to be written. Mark somehow that their time is erroneous
        String time = "ERROR";    

        if (timeTakenInSeconds[i] > -1) {
              time = "" + timeTakenInSeconds[i];
        }

        showHorseThatFinished.append(horseName[i]);
        showHorseThatFinished.append("\t");
        showHorseThatFinished.append(time);
        showHorseThatFinished.append("\n");
    }
}

    return showHorseThatFinished.toString();
}
```

There is no need for this piece of code anymore

```
    String timeOfHorse = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < noOfHorseInList; i++)
    {
        if(timeTakenInSeconds[i] > -1)
        {
            timeOfHorse = timeOfHorse + "\n" + timeTakenInSeconds[i];
        }
    }
```

Just

```
  System.out.println(showHorseThatFinished);
```

Answer (score -1):

How about changing the following line in the for loop to -

```
timeOfHorse = timeOfHorse + "\t" + timeTakenInSeconds[i];
```

Comment: No. He needs to print the name in the same line as the time

Comment: You are printing all the Horses one after another because you are creating the String in the `finishers` method with a `\t`. That's another piece of code that you might have to change

Comment: considering editing or deleting this post it doesn't answer the question and provides little effort

Comment: @SethKitchen +1 to your comment on the question.